# How can I free any dynamic memory allocated inside a function?

Tags: c++, pointers, memory, dynamic, allocation

I'm working on a problem and I've been asked to create a function that returns a pointer. The program I wrote works fine and all; however, I create dynamic memory allocation inside my function called `*newArray` and I don't think I'm freeing that allocated memory the pointer `ptr2` is pointing to inside this function. Is there a way to release this memory?

I was thinking of adding another parameter to the function - the `ptr2` pointer from the main function - and just alter that pointer inside the function, but that defeats the purpose of the function returning a pointer. Any thoughts here?

**Here's my code:**

```
//Problem #12
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

void SizeEntry(int*);
void DataEntry(int*, int);
void ShowArray(int *, int);
int *newArray(int *, int);

int main()
{
    int size, new_size;
    int *ptr=nullptr, *ptr2 = nullptr;

    //grab size and dynamically allocate an array to the entered size
    SizeEntry(&size);
    ptr = new int[size];

    //make size of second array
    new_size=size+1;

    //Fill array with data and make a new copy w/ requirements
    DataEntry(ptr, size);
    ptr2 = newArray(ptr, size);

    cout<<"\nHere is the first array: \n";
    ShowArray(ptr, size);
    cout<<"Here is the new array: \n";
    ShowArray(ptr2, new_size);

    //free allocated array
    delete [] ptr;
    delete [] ptr2;
    ptr = nullptr;
    ptr2 = nullptr;

    return 0;
}
void SizeEntry(int *size)
{
    cout<<"Enter the size of your list: ";
    cin>>*size;
    while(*size<0)
    {
        cout<<"Size must be non-negative, enter another number: ";
        cin>>*size;
    }
}
void DataEntry(int *ptr, int size)
{
    for(int count = 0; count<size; count++)
    {
        cout<<"Enter data for entry #"<<(count+1)<<": ";
        cin>>*(ptr+count);
        while(*(ptr+count)<0)
        {
            cout<<"Data point cannot be negative, try again: ";
            cin>>*(ptr + count);
        }
    }
}
void ShowArray(int *ptr, int size)
{
    for(int count=0; count<size; count++)
        cout<<*(ptr+count)<<" ";
    cout<<endl;
}
int *newArray(int *ptr, int size)
{
    int *ptr2=nullptr;
    int new_size = size+1;
    int counter=0;

    ptr2 = new int[new_size];

    for(int count=0; count<new_size; count++)
    {
        if(count==0)
            ptr2[count]=0;
        else
        {
            ptr2[count]=ptr[counter];
            counter++;
        }
    }        
    return ptr2;
}
```

Comment: Consider smart pointers

Comment: You are releasing that memory with `delete[] ptr2` when you're done using it. You can't release it before.

Comment: Hi Sami, that delete [] ptr2  is in main and releases the memory created in main that that ptr2 pointer points to, but I also create another one in *newArray function.

Comment: @SamiKuhmonen : He is talking about inside of *newArray. The only thing he doesn't do is to delete [] ptr1 in *newArray.  He creates ptr2 in it, moves everything over from ptr1 but he doesn't get rid of ptr1. However, he immediately uses ptr1 in the main program after returning from newArray(). So if he releases it - the program would core dump when it tried using it. So I don't see a problem really. He does release both ptr1 & ptr2 in the main program. *shrug* That should get it.

Comment: It releases the memory that the pointer is pointing to, which is the memory that was allocated in your function. I see no problem with this code, other than the fact that it uses `new` to create dynamic arrays, which is generally a terrible idea.

Comment: @MarkManning Yeah, I don't really see an issue in this code as it's written. Maybe needs some clarification.

Comment: Side note: last two lines in the main function (`ptr = nullptr` and `ptr2 = nullptr`) are useless.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**To Free the memory allocated by "new Operator" in C++, Just use delete operator and nothing else.**

No need to assign null to the pointer whose memory is already freed by delete operator.

PS: IF YOU INTENDED TO USE THAT POINTER AGAIN, ONLY THEN ASSIGN IT TO NULL.

So in your case the last two line of code are useless unless you are intended to use that pointer again.

```
 //free allocated array
    delete [] ptr; 
    delete [] ptr2;
    ptr = nullptr; //Useless as memory is already free assigned to ptr 
    ptr2 = nullptr;//Useless as memory is already free assigned to ptr2
```

In the *newArray function you are returning one pointer i.e ptr2.

When you return ptr2 a copy of the value (an address) of ptr2 is made and returned to the caller.  ptr2 was declared with automatic storage duration. It is the memory it refers to that must be freed and you are doing it in main as ptr2 of *newArray is assigned to ptr2 of main function.

**PS :If you have any doubts debug it in Visual Studio you will get the clear Idea.**

Comment: So the memory allocated in the newArray function is also freed by the delete operator?

Comment: @Francisco : i modified my answer. hope it will clear the idea

Comment: Thanks! I've validated that through my textbook as there is an example used there that uses a function to create a dynamic memory array, populates it, and returns a pointer to the array. It also creates another dynamically allocated array in the main function and assigns that to the pointer outputted from the function. When freeing the memory in the main function, the example applies the delete operator to the pointer created in the main function.

Comment: Also mentioned in the textbook - as this itself seals an answer to this question - is that functions using the new operator to allocate a section of memory will remain allocated until the delete operator is used or the program ends.

Comment: Why do you suggest to NOT assign the null operator to the pointer whose memory is already freed by the delete operator? My textbook gives me 2 reasons why I should:   1. Prevents code from inadvertently using the pointer to access the area of memory that was freed  and 2. Prevents errors from occurring if delete is accidentally called on the pointer again.

Comment: It's precautionary. If you intended to use that pointer again in your program then you should initialize it to null (which is not in this case) otherwise it is not necessary. While using delete operator, memory gets deallocated but the pointer is still pointing to some random location and it doesn't affect your program until you are going to do some operations on pointer whose memory get deallocated  by delete. In a nutshell, if u r intended to use that pointer again, assign it to null otherwise it will just increase line of code.

Answer (score 1):

You are freeing ptr2 in main. To this you assign prt2 of your function before with your return value. So both pointers are pointing to the same memory as this is the thought of pointers.
When you free ptr2 in main, you automatically free ptr2 in your function because they are the same --> see your assignment. So from my point of view there is now problem with allocated memory.

Comment: I do not think this is correct. But I could be wrong here. The function newArray() does a new command which does not point to the same memory location as ptr1. THE DATA might have the same pointers but the arrays I think are different.

Comment: Hmm, this one: return ptr2; is assigned to this one right here:  ptr2 = newArray(ptr, size); and this ptr2 is released in main, so where is the problem? He can not release the pointer before returning it :-) but as ptr2 in main and ptr2 in the newArray-function are the same, he releases everything --> I´m only watching at ptr2 right now.

Comment: Yes, I think his concern is unjustified. So I must be blind because I don't see a problem with the code. :-)

Comment: Ok, so Francisco, if this seems plausible to you, please give it a vote or mark it as answer, thanks

Comment: @Marcel Is there any way to know if this truly frees the memory allocated in the function? PS: I'm fairly new to programming.

Comment: @Francisco: Put the contents of the body of your main function (excluding the return statement) into an infinite loop. Remove all input statements (`cin`), and set the size of the array to a large hard coded value, like 10 million. Run the program, and if you have a memory leak, the program should be terminated fairly quickly with a bad alloc exception.

Comment: if you use Visual Studio, you could use the Memory Usage Tool: https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/visualstudioalm/2014/11/13/memory-usage-tool-while-debugging-in-visual-studio-2015/

Answer (score 0):

Come on, I don't see any problem here. But I think it worth to tell you that, ptr2 in main function is assigned by the returned pointer of newArray function, and that main-ptr2 is logically identical to the newArray-ptr2.

When I say "logically", I mean of course they are to different pointers. Pointer is variable too, so main-ptr2 and newArray-ptr2 are two different pointers, they are stored in different places in the memory. HOWEVER, they have the same value, which is an address information of some other variable in the memory. Having the same value means they are pointing to the same memory block.

Me and my brother are two different people, I am pointing to a beautiful women and tell my brother "hey, look at that beautiful lay!", and now, my brother also pointing to that pretty lady.

So, two pointer, one target. If you try to release the target, using `delete ptr2` in main, the target pointed by both main-ptr2 and newArray-ptr2 will be destroy.

BTW, newArray-ptr2 actually no longer exists, because it is an auto variable of newArray function.

Answer (score 0):

Think in terms of low-level memory details. Inside the *newArray* function you are allocating a memory chunk through *new* and assigning the base-address of that chunk to *ptr2* pointer.

You, then return the *ptr2* pointer from the *newArray* function and assign that pointer to the *ptr2* pointer inside of *main()*.

Ultimately, you free the memory chunk held by you through the *delete* statement, wherein you tell the machine to free the contiguously-allocated memory chunk pointed by *ptr2*.

I do not see any reason for any memory leak. For better understanding, I would recommend running this program of yours through a debugger(gdb).